# Connect to Azure DevOps Artifact from Visual Studio (NuGet)

Tags: azure, nuget, visual-studio-2019, azure-artifacts

I successfully setted up and integrate Azure DevOps Artifacts with build pipeline.
Now I want to connect Visual Studio 2019 with this private feed, but the only way i found to make it works is to generate a PAT on my account and use it to add the feed to the Nuget' sources on my machine.

I also tried, without success, the Microsoft Artifact CredProvider.

There is a way to register the source without use PAT?

**UPDATE**
As suggested by [Levi-Lu-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11882186/levi-lu-msft), as for now, the solution is to use the AzDevOps account as "Visual Studio Account" in Visual Studio. If, as in my case, the account used for AzDevOps is different from the VS Account, than the only way I found to make it work, is to register a NuGet Source with a PAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed below steps to add azure artifacts feed to my visual studio. And i didnot use PAT to consume the packages.

Go to Tools menu-->NuGet Package Manager -->Package Manager Setting-->Package Sources-->Select the green plus in the upper-right corner and enter the name and source URL of your azure feed.

**Consume the packages**:

Right click the project-->Manage nuget packages. Find a package you want to use. (You probably need to sign in your account(account used to login to AzureDevOps) in visual studio).

You can also go to Tools--> NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console and run the `Install-Package` command to install the package.

Please see documents for more information.

[Consume NuGet packages in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops)

[Use NuGet with Azure DevOps Services feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you! I'already followed the documentation and the signin windows appears correctly, but when I click on my account I see an Unauthorized error in the console log. I checked that I'm authroized to access to the private feed (I'm in the "Project Collection Administrator" that has the Owner permission, but I tried even to add my account directly as a contributor). I thing that there is a problem with the login windows:  I click on my account that is signed as "Windows logged in", but if I click the "Enter with another account, and re-enter my account credentials, the result is the same.

Comment: @SamueleFurnari Could you try deleting the VS cached credentials from registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp`.

Comment: I checked the reg key but it's empty. I also tried, in visual studio, to change authentication from "Internal browser" to "System browser". In this case, after entered uid & pass, the result is the same "Unable to load the service index for source: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../_packaging/.../nuget/v3/index.json".

Comment: It may be that the problem is that the account used to login to AzureDevOps (customer account) is different from the account logged-in in visual studio (my organization subscription)?

Comment: @SamueleFurnari You should login with the account used to login to AzureDevOps.

Comment: thanks! after this the access to the feed works as expected... So I suppose that the problem is that even if in the login windows, I select an account different from the account logged in with visual studio, Visual Studio use always the "first account"

Comment: @SamueleFurnari That's great it finally worked. Could you accept above answer if you think it qualifies as the answer? Thanks1

Comment: Sure! And I edit my question to highlight the solution!